# Anytime scraped (php) output is positive or negative number, color accordingly

Tags: php, css, xpath, colors

I'm not good at PHP, but with some help, I've figured out how to output specific values via scrape/XPath. I'm trying to rig it so if the number it outputs is a positive number, color is green. If negative, color red.

Taking this random website as an example, this is currently giving a value number as an output

```
<?php

    $doc = new DOMDocument;
     // We don't want to bother with white spaces
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

    $doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
    $doc->recover = true;

    $doc->loadHTMLFile('http://www.moneycontrol.com/markets/global-indices/');

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

    $query = "//div[@class='MT10']";


    $entries = $xpath->query($query);
    foreach ($entries as $entry) 
    {
        $result = trim($entry->textContent); 
        $ret_ = explode(' ', $result);
        //make sure every element in the array don't start or end with blank

        foreach ($ret_ as $key=>$val)
        {
            $ret_[$key]=trim($val);
        }

        //delete the empty element and the element is blank "\n" "\r" "\t"
        //I modify this line
        $ret_ = array_values(array_filter($ret_,deleteBlankInArray));

        //echo the last element
        echo $ret_[26];
    }
}
```

I know some of what the solution would be, but I'm not skilled enough to be able to get it working together. I'd appreciate any assistance with this if at all possible. This is the type of thing that needs to be added, but my unique situation is that this is scraped data, random numbers.

**CSS**

```
.value-positive {
  color: #0cdb02;
}

.value-negative {
color: #fe0000;
}
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
    $classname = $output < 0 ? 'negative' : 'positive';
    print "<span class='value-$classname'>$output</span>";
?>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: sure, thanks. My php file is outputting scraped data, always a number. Numbers like -40.3%.  80.30, etc.   Right now they appear black, by default, or whatever my css has specified. Instead, I'd like the php to automatically color the number, red if it's a negative number like -30.3. Or green if it's a positive number, like .03 or 20.04. These will be RANDOM numbers, so I need something that automatically colors it based off the value of the randomly scraped/outputted value.

Comment: sorry, not sure how to make it any more clear at this point. my website scrapes data from other websites via php. it outputs onto my site, number values like "30.04". I'd like to add a php function, where whatever the number that my php outputs, it's AUTOMATICALLY colored red if a negative number, or automatically colored green if it's positive. That's the simplest way I know how to explain it.

Comment: Ah! Awesome! Thank you Sahil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this simplest one. Hope this is understandable and is what you are looking for. You need to use [`intval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php),

> You should define a function like this and invoke it when you need.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/820401)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .value-positive {
              color: #0cdb02;
            }

            .value-negative {
                color: #fe0000;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php

        $output='-40.3%';

        addClass($output);

        function addClass($output)
        {
            $classname = intval($output) < 0 ? 'negative' : 'positive';
            print "<span class='value-$classname'>$output</span>";
        }

        ?>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey Sahil! That's awesome, thank you. I have one issue though, it's outputting BOTH a negative and positive value for me. Where I just want it to output the negative one, if the number is negative. And the positive, if it's positive. I basically put your code on my php page, below the data scraping php

Comment: <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE^E_WARNING);
include_once "global.php";

        //filename of the file
if(!cache_start("ripplecurrentprice.php")){

$doc = new DOMDocument;

// We don't want to bother with white spaces
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

// Most HTML Developers are chimps and produce invalid markup...
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->recover = true;

$doc->loadHTMLFile('https://coinmarketcap.com/');



$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$query = "//tr[@id='id-ripple']";

Comment: Thank you Sahil, this wasn't quite what I was looking for. Because it requires me to input that number, as well as specficy if it's negative or positive. with the xpath in my php, the numbers are outputted automatically via a datascrape, and I need it to function in a way that I never have to input the numbers manually. In other words, at one point the data scrape may output -30, then 30 mins later the source data has changed, and the output now outputs +40.04. I'm just looking for a way for the php to color it automatically. But this is still valuable information. Thank you for your help.

Comment: for ex if I could just change the code you provided, to say $output='echo $ret_[7];   that would do it. I doubt that I have the coding right though.

Comment: @Masteryogurt It will work definitely fine, if you want data to be updated as you said in previous comment you need to use ajax, which will do the work for you.

Comment: Sahil, yes I just did it and you are right, that works. Would you mind doing something for me that would be extremely helpful? Would you be able to adjust my PHP code I originally submitted, to combine it with this function? Currently I'm outputting the number TWO times, because I have two php functions. I don't know how to combine it properly without breaking the code. I'm so close! Thank you very much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147323/discussion-between-sahil-gulati-and-masteryogurt).